# dataTables recover iDisplayLength

Tags: jquery

I use the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('# Table_id').DataTable({
    'iDisplayLength': '50',
    "aLengthMenu": [
      [20, 50, 100, 200],
      [20, 50, 100, 200]
    ]
  });
});
```

I want to recover `iDisplayLength`?

Comment: with any specific value or it's dynamic?

Comment: with dynamic value @BhumiShah

Comment: you question is not clear. please explain again

Comment: I want to create a variable contains iDisplayLength, to use it
example: var x = iDisplayLength;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('# Table_id').DataTable({
    'iDisplayLength': '50',
    "aLengthMenu": [
      [20, 50, 100, 200],
      [20, 50, 100, 200]
    ]
  });
  var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
  var x = oSettings._iDisplayLength;
});
```